# Example of matrix $A\neq I$ such that $A^3=I$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Let $A \neq I$ be a $3 \times 3$ matrix. I need to find an example of $A$ that satisfies $A^3 = I$.

Is there any "smart" way to do this? All I can think of is to either multiply $A$ for 3 times and then try to guess the factors or try to solve $A^2 = A^{-1}$. In either case I feel that it can be solved in a smarter way. Any ideas?

Comment: Try thinking of rotation matrices.

Comment: Are your matrix entries real or complex?

Comment: Where should the coefficients live in?

Comment: Over the complex numbers then $e^{2\pi i /3}I$ works.

Comment: Take
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}.
$$

Comment: Entries of matrix are real. Rotation matrix worked - I just took a rotation over $x$ by $\frac{2\pi}{3}$. hunter - I've found this example earlier but I can't see how I could have come to this. Is it a straight guess?

Comment: Hunter's example is a [Permutation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix).

Comment: Since $A$ satisfies $p(A) = 0$, where $p(x) = x^3 - 1 = (x^2 + x + 1) (x - 1)$---the quadratic polynomial in the factorization is irreducible over $\Bbb R$---and $A$ is diagonalizable (over $\Bbb C$). Now, the only possible characteristic polynomials $c_A$ of $A$ are $p(x)$ and $(x - 1)^3$, so up to similarity, the only $A$ satisfying $A^3 = I$ are $$A_0 = \pmatrix{\cdot&-1&\cdot\\1&-1&\cdot\\\cdot&\cdot&1}$$ and $I$, that is, all solutions $A$ of $A^3 = I$ other than $I$ are of the form $B A_0 B^{-1}$, where $B$ is an invertible matrix. In that sense, Hunter's solution is the only one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fix $3$ linearly independent vectors $e_1$, $e_2$, and $e_3$ of $\Bbb R^3$ (the vectors of the standard basis, say) and consider the map $f\colon\Bbb R^3\longrightarrow\Bbb R^3$ such that $f(e_1)=e_2$, $f(e_2)=e_3$ and that $f(e_3)=e_1$. Now, let $A$ be the matrix of $f$ with respect to some basis of $\Bbb R^3$. Can you check that such a matrix will work?

Comment: Okay I think I've got it. We can actually think of this as a permutation right? So by applying $f$ map to a $(e_1,e_2,e_3)$ matrix we'll get permutation 
$
\begin{pmatrix}
e_1,e_2,e_3 \\
e_2.e_3,e_1
\end{pmatrix}
$
which has an order of $3$.

Comment: Not only we *can* think of this as a permutation, as that is *how* I thought about this.

Comment: @carlos  I would like to know what is the idea behind this? How did you come up with this?

Comment: @AmanPandey I thought in terms of a permutation of order $3$.

Answer (score 0):

If you allow $A$ take complex values. Below is a solution.

By condition, $f(\lambda) = \lambda^3 - 1 = (\lambda - 1)(\lambda - \omega_1)(\lambda - \omega_2)$ is an annihilating polynomial of $A$, where
$\omega_1 = e^{i\frac{2}{3}\pi}, \omega_2 = e^{-i\frac{2}{3}\pi}$, but $g(\lambda) = \lambda - 1$ is not an annihilating polynomial. So there are some possibilities of how the minimal polynomial $d(\lambda)$ of $A$ can be. For example, if $d(\lambda) = \lambda - \omega_1$. Then $A$ has $3$ multiple eigenvalues $\omega_1$, in this case, $A = \mathrm{diag}(\omega_1, \omega_1, \omega_1)$.

You can check that $A \neq I$, but $A^3 = I$. You can also construct different $A$ by taking $d(\lambda) = \lambda - \omega_2$, $d(\lambda) = (\lambda - 1)(\lambda - \omega_1)$, etc.

If you require the entries to be real numbers, then it is easy to transform one complex solution such as $\mathrm{diag}(\omega_1, \omega_1, 1)$ to the real rotation matrix as below:
\begin{equation*}
A = \begin{pmatrix}
\cos\frac{2}{3}\pi & \sin\frac{2}{3}\pi & 0 \\
-\sin\frac{2}{3}\pi & \cos\frac{2}{3}\pi & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
-\frac{1}{2} & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & 0 \\
-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & -\frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation*}